# SQL indexing made some queries take longer. Why?

Tags: java, sqlite, indexing

I have made a database which holds around 24 millions records on house sales in the UK. I have written a small java program which queries the database and displays the results in a table. The user searches a postcode or a partial postcode and all matches are displayed. I originally worked on an un-indexed table and full postcodes (e.g. lk4 5th) took about 5 seconds to perform. larger searches (e.g. lk4 5) took about 8 seconds and very large searches (l) took about 25 seconds. I was asked to index the database as that would increase the speed of queries. I remade the table with the following SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
id TEXT,price INTEGER,sale_date TEXT,postcode TEXT,
prop_type CHAR,newbuild CHAR,leasetype CHAR,
paon TEXT,saon TEXT,street TEXT,locality TEXT,
town TEXT,district TEXT,county TEXT,category CHAR,status CHAR
);
.mode csv
.import C:/Users/(path goes here)
CREATE INDEX i_postcode ON sales(postcode collate nocase);
```

This has improved the speed of searches that return less results (e.g. lk4 5th - lk4) significantly however for the larger searches it has increased it to an unusable amount of time. 5 mins +.

The only query being performed is a very simple one which is:

```
SELECT price, sale_date, postcode, paon, street, locality FROM sales WHERE postcode LIKE ?;
```

I have used `Javas built` in `VisualVM software` to view the CPU samples and it seems that `org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.step[native]` is the area of concentration which takes so long to process. I am completely new to using databases and have been unable to find anything online that suggests that this should have increased the processing time. If you have any ideas of what I can do to increase to speed of the large searches, that would be very much appreciated.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Can you please share the query which is taking long time?

Comment: Hi Khwaja. The query is "SELECT price, sale_date, postcode, paon, street, locality FROM sales WHERE postcode LIKE ?" and the ? would be something like "S%". So basically, select everything from sales where the postcode begins with S.

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/poor-database-indexing-sql-query-performance-killer-recommendations/

Comment: This might be helpful https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: Thanks for the link @CR241. I have read a few articles such as the one that you provided however they always seem to apply to much more complicated DB structures and queries. As mine is just a simple single table with a really basic search, I can't seem to apply the advice given in these articles to improve the performance of this search.

Comment: @Justin Yes that is indeed very helpful, much appreciated. Basically suggests that the LIKE statement with the wildcard can take longer with the less information that it has to go off. I will see if I can have a look into this and hopefully get it sped up :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue might well be that postcode isn't what would be considered a high cardinality especially when the fixed part (before the wildcard) is shorter (longer search/more results) and thus that at these longer searches the binary search becomes a 0(n) linear scan.

I've never tried it but if the length of the the fixed part of the search argument is less than 3 (so l%, lk% but not lk4%) then using **+postcode** would do a linear scan on the more efficient **rowid** i.e. **+postcode** says don't user the index.

- *length of 3 based upon lk4 being ok*

The following shows the postcode reverting to the **rowid** SCAN with the **+** coded :-

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS i_postcode;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales(
id TEXT,price INTEGER,sale_date TEXT,postcode TEXT,
prop_type CHAR,newbuild CHAR,leasetype CHAR,
paon TEXT,saon TEXT,street TEXT,locality TEXT,
town TEXT,district TEXT,county TEXT,category CHAR,status CHAR
);
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
SELECT price, sale_date, postcode, paon, street, locality FROM sales WHERE postcode LIKE 's%';
CREATE INDEX  IF NOT EXISTS i_postcode ON sales(postcode collate nocase);
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
SELECT price, sale_date, postcode, paon, street, locality FROM sales WHERE +postcode LIKE 's%';
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
SELECT price, sale_date, postcode, paon, street, locality FROM sales WHERE postcode LIKE 's%';
```

#### Result 1 - No index

[image]

#### Result 2 - Index forced to not be used (same as result 1)

[image]

#### Result 3 - + not used so Index used

[image]

Comment: Very informative and helpful answer, thank you very much. This did indeed set the search time for the larger result search back to how it was but still kept the speed on the smaller searches. I will use this until I can find a way to speed up searches such as 'lk' etc. Thank you very much for your help.